# Perl-gtk2 error : unable to build perl-gtk2 successfully

Tags: perl, gtk, gtk3, gtk2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX0xv.jpg)

While building my code in getting error : can't locate GTK2.pm @INC (you may need to install gtk2 module) 
So I tried to build perl-gtk2 source code on RHEL 8.1. I'm using perl 5.26 version. After building perl script Makefile.pl, I'm running MAKE and it's not getting build successfully. Some of the .pod files are not getting generated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. instead of posting a bad picture of your screen, you should post the error as text in your question, use backticks to show it as code. Moreover just tag your question with what you are using, or do you really use gtk + gtk2 + gtk3? Please also read [how to ask a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

As shown by your image (and please don't post images of text - copy the actual text into your question) the error message talked about "Gtk.pm", not "GTK.pm". Attention to detail is very important for programmers :-)

There's no need to build anything. The required module is already available in the standard RHEL package repositories.

```
$ sudo yum install perl-Gtk2
```

Comment: Perl-Gtk2 el7 package is not installable on RHEL 8.1

Comment: @deepakgoswami: Well, no, it wouldn't be, would it? But I don't know why you're trying to install the RHEL7 version on RHEL8. Your `yum` should be configured correctly to install RPMs from the correct package repository. If it's not, then you should take that up with the sysadmin.